# Git clone/push/pull commands fail without error after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, virtualbox, virtualization, git

Git worked without any problems in my ubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox VM hosted in Windows 7. But since I've upgraded the VM to 18.04 today all the commands `git clone`, `git pull`, `git push` fail without error. I've tried reinstalling git and rebooting but to no avail. `git status` and `git commit`, etc still work fine. It only seems to be the commands that involve connecting to a remote origin that fail. Unfortunately there's no error message, even when I use a `--verbose` flag on the commands.

I am behind a proxy and usually clone repos using https and a personal access token from GitHub. I think the first time I tried `git push` after upgrading to 18.04 there  was a crash report but I must have asked not to be told again because I haven't seen them since. Now I can't track down any related bug report for this...

Comment: A workaround I've found is to `git clone` a repo using the git: URL rather than the https: URL for the repo - i.e., use ssh rather than https to authenticate. This works from the commandline but unfortunately other tools like PyCharm for example don't like the ssh approach (Git push/pull fails without error). Which means I'm forced to use the commandline for cloning, pushing, pulling until a proper solution is found.

Comment: Ok - I can make PyCharm work with ssh if I configure it to use the native ssh executable rather than the built-in one (Settings > Version Control > Git > SSH Executable = Native)